# Есть ли в c# удобная функция поиска массива байтов внутри другого массива байтов?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
for (int i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++)
{
    if (fs[i] == 64)
    {
        if (fs[i + 1] == 115)
        {
            if (fs[i + 2] == 46)
            {
                if (fs[i + 3] == 119)
                {
                    if (fs[i + 4] == 104)
                    {
                        if (fs[i + 5] == 97)
                        {
                            if (fs[i + 6] == 116)
                            {
                                if (fs[i + 7] == 115)
                                {
                                    if (fs[i + 8] == 97)
                                    {
                                        byte[] noom = { fs[i - 11], fs[i - 10], fs[i - 9], fs[i - 8], fs[i - 7], fs[i - 6], fs[i - 5], fs[i - 4], fs[i - 3], fs[i - 2], fs[i - 1] };
                                        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(noom, 0, noom.Length);
                                        if (Convert.ToInt64(str) > 0)
                                        {
                                            numbers.Add(str);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас использую что то типо этого. Неудобно

Comment: [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VladD, Как я понял - эта функция сравнивает последовательности на равенство именно, а не на включение

Comment: Ну, добавьте ещё Skip и Take к исходной последовательности, да, и тот же цикл по `i`.

Comment: а кто мешает исправить код на что-то на подобие `var need = true; var values = new int[]{64,115, 46,119,..};for(int j=0;j<9;j++){need=need&fs[i + j] == values[j]}` а далее если need, то..

Comment: @Mart правильно ли я понял, что вас не устраивает именно написание длинного кода, а не время его исполнения?

Comment: @Monomax; Да, громоздкость не устраивает. По быстродействию вроде как самый быстрый вариант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
var pattern = new byte[] { 64, 115, 46, 119, 104, 97, 116, 115, 97 };
const int patternOffset = 11;
for (int i = patternOffset; i < fs.Length - pattern.Length; i++)
{
    if (!fs.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern))
        continue;

    var numBytes = fs.Skip(i - patternOffset).Take(patternOffset);
    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(numBytes, 0, numBytes.Length);
    if (long.TryParse(str, out var num))
        numbers.Add(num);
}
```

Обратите внимание на начальный и конечный индексы в цикле `for`: без этой поправки вы рискуете вылететь за границы диапазона.

---

Как подсказывает @АндрейNOP в комментариях, можно воспользоваться более изящным

```
new ArraySegment(fs, i, pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern)
```

и

```
var numBytes = new ArraySegment(fs, i - patternOffset, patternOffset);
```

Comment: Вместо комбинации `.Skip().Take()` можно воспользоваться `ArraySegment`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Круто, не знал! Спасибо!

Comment: А ещё можно было б воспользоваться Array.IndexOf() в стартовом условии в цикле: int i = Array.IndexOf(fs[0]); и в самом цикле вместо перебора всех i при несовпадении SequenceEqual делать i = Array.Skip(i).IndexOf(fs[0]); continue;

Comment: @Александр: Если развить вашу идею, можно воспользоваться любым из алгоритмов поиска подстроки. Да хоть [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).